# How to avoid repeating self when defining subclasses in python?

Tags: python, string, class, oop

I'm trying to build an algorithm which constructs funny but grammatical sentences. As a part of this, I need to classify words into different categories, and want to explore using OOP to achieve this, but I am struggling to avoid violating DRY. Below is a reduced example.

```
class word:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.firstLetter = self.name[0]
        self.length = len(name)



class noun(word):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        super().__init__(name)




class agent(noun):
  def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        super().__init__(name)
```

I would like all words to share certein methods and properties, e.g. having a "length" equal to the length of their name. However, I only need an object to be named at the very lowest level (in this case agent), and thus it seems superflous to feature a name in the **init** of each subclass.

In summary, is there any way of acheive the same end result of the above code without having to write the following ad nauseam?

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name=name
    super().__init__(name)
```

Comment: Do not override constructors of child classes?

Comment: could you please show me how to write the class definition of "noun" without doing that?

Comment: `class noun(word): pass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following dryes up your code:

```
class word:

    firstLetter: str = ''

    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.length: int = len(name)
        if self.length:
            self.firstLetter = self.name[0]        


class noun(word):
    pass


class agent(noun):
    pass
```

Comment: You should add `else: self.firstLetter=None` (Or something equivalent)

Comment: `firstLetter` is already defined as a class variable: `firstLetter  = ''` @barny